# Which FreeBSD config is best to use for compilation of SMP kernel for qemu vexpress-a9

Tags: arm, embedded, freebsd, qemu, cortex-a

Which kernel config file is best to use ( and eventually modify ) for FreeBSD for arm versatile Cortex A9 platform ( vexpress-a9 in qemu ).
I need to compile and run kernel with SMP support.

It's intended to be run under qemu this way

```
qemu-system-arm -M vexpress-a9 -smp cores=4 (...other params...)
```

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD/arm and FreeBSD/armv6 support a large range of ARM CPUs and development boards. Not every peripheral is supported on every CPU or board, though work continues towards this and contributions are always welcome. Conversely, many CPUs and boards not listed may work with only minimal changes needed.

Listing all supported devices on all CPUs and boards is impractical here, however much information can be obtained from the mailing list and archives, [the FreeBSD/arm Wiki pages](https://wiki.freebsd.org/FreeBSD/arm), and also from the [Kernel Configuration files](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/sys/arm/conf/)

PS:

[Versatile Express support in QEMU](https://wiki.linaro.org/PeterMaydell/QemuVersatileExpress)